# Chained Routing in ExpressJS with path variables

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to develop a system of chaining Express routes in Node.js. The idea is that you could have a url like:

```
api.foo/<someFooId>/bar/<someBarId>
```

the root js file would have

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var foo = require('./routes/foo');
app.use('/foo', foo);
```

then `routes/foo.js` would be:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bar = require('./bar');
app.use('/:fooId/bar', bar);
```

then the URL pattern shown above would ultimately be handled by `routes/bar.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/:barId', function(req, res) {
    ...
}
```

This system correctly routes requests to the above URL pattern to the route for `bar`, however, the `req` object does not contain the `fooId`. I am wondering if anyone knows a way for my `bar` route to have access to the `fooId`

Comment: What is your main goal to accomplish here?

Comment: My goal is to implement handling for the URL pattern shown, using chained routing modules.

Comment: Out of curiosity, readability, why not just `router.get('/:fooId/:barId')`?

Comment: What if `foo` has sub array `baz` as well? It needs to distinguish between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do what Datsik said, `router.get('api/foo/:fooId/bar/:barId')`

if you absolutely need to keep those two seperate, you can attach the value for `:fooid` to `req` and then attach the `bar` route.

Something like, 
In Foo.js

```
router.get('/api/foo/:fooId', function (req, res, next) {
    // build data on request.
    req.fooId = req.params.fooId;
    req.test = 'this is how you add data to req';



    next();
});

// attach bar
router.get('/api/foo/:fooId', require('./bar'));
```

In bar.js

```
router.get('/bar/:barId', function (req, res, next) {
    var fooId = req.fooId; // its getting the value from `req`
})
```

Comment: This doesn't address my issue at all. I am trying to gain access to path variables parsed by a higher level of middleware, though I will take the advice for the URL structure under advisement.

Comment: Attach path variables to "req" and you have access to them throughout the route stack.

Comment: that is what i am trying to do. i don"t understand how. if you edit you answer to include that info, and it works, i'll accept it

Comment: Edited, give it a try.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, basically. I tweaked it so that not every call to `/api/foo/:fooId` gets routed to the bar handlers, just if it is `/api/foo/:fooId/bar`. Please update one thing if you get a chance. The last line in Foo.js should be `router.use(...` instead of `router.get(...`

Comment: I would still implicity write routes with different `verbs`. Even if you are having the same url for a `get` and a `post`, i would still write them as 2 separate routes instead of `use`.  Why do i recommend it? Maintainability.

Comment: well, it's something to consider, but when I tried it, it didn't work. Changing to `use` made it work. In the file for `bar`, I still write separate routes for each verb. Thank you very much for your input on this. Thank you for your patience the last 10 days. I've had my hands full with finals. I finally get to work on my own projects again

Answer (score 0):

> Forget all I wrote before if you happen to read it

You will have to leave the params to the router itself. That is, the router has the regexes and does the match to get the params out of the url.

So if you want the parameters you will have to do something like this:

```
var express = require('express');

// helper to get some info
function info(req){
  var params = JSON.stringify(req.params);
  return (
    '<ul>' +
      '<li>' + ' path: ' + req.originalUrl + '</li>' +
      '<li>' + ' params: ' + params + '</li>' +
    '</ul>'
  );
}

var fooRouter = express.Router();

fooRouter.get('/:id', function(req, res){
  res.send(info(req));
});

fooRouter.get('/:id/bar', function(req, res){
  res.send(info(req));
});

var app = express();

app.use('/page', fooRouter);

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('server listening on http://localhost:3000');
});
```